# F12/F2 not working & Lenovo logo not showing after installing Ubuntu (Single-boot)

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Edge 15, of which I installed Ubuntu on (removed Windows).

I have to access the BIOS. However, the F12 key won't open it, and the Lenovo logo won't even display. Instead, it goes directly to Ubuntu asking me for my password to decrypt the system.

I need help accessing BIOS

**EDIT:** It seems the BIOS itself maybe messed up. When I press F2, I get a black screen, and it stays there until reboot

Comment: Usually it's F2, not F12, for Lenovo and with UEFI fast boot enabled there's almost no time to stop the boot process. Try pressing the proper key and kept it while powering on. In any case this isn't a Ubuntu question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware issue and nothing to do with Ubuntu